# ROS Answers SE migration: roscore error

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run roscore command i face the following error.I tried alot to get solve but in vain.Any one who know please help.how to solve this

```
logging to /home/faiz/.ros/log/fc2de17e-50a6-11e1-93e0-0024811c47cc/roslaunch-faiz-4674.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Unable to contact my own server at [http://faiz:48024/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

A common cause is that the machine cannot ping itself.  Please check
for errors by running:

    ping faiz

For more tips, please see

    http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12901/roscore-error/) by [faizi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1741/faizi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-02-05**:
Can you please give more information? Can you ping faiz? Did you go through the network setup steps? Did you try setting ROS_IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you ping your own computer? If you execute:

```
ping faiz
```

Does the ping come pack? You could consider setting your ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME variables. For example  add:

```
export ROS_IP="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

to your .bashrc, where the xs are your IP number. If you don't know where to find your IP, use ifconfig.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2012-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2